# Google Cloud SQL connection error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to Google App engine and I have tried to run an demo application called guestbook to connect to Google cloud sql from the Google app engine with app-engine-sdk version 1-7.0. But each time I am getting an error  saying "java.lang.IllegalStateException: System property rdbms.driver must be set at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.registerDriver(LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.java:80)". I double check my code and every thing looks ok, and I still have no glue where the error coming from.

Below is a snippet of my connection code :

c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://my_instance/my_database");

and mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin is in the class path,

and I have enable Google cloud sql in the Google app engine,

and I have checked the use of Google Cloud instance in the app engine as well with the my instance of the database, database name, login , and password,

and I am using Eclipse Juno.

I think I have missed something important; so would you please help me if you know what I have missed.

Thank you very much in advance,

Minh

Answer (score 0):

Once you are new to GAE I recommend to give a try on the Big Table database. Using it you will not have to setup any database localy. So just the eclipse plugin will be enough for your first test. The Guestbook uses this database so it will be easier to follow the tutorial.